# Im unable to set a Bitmap using FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to make a drawing application. I created a function that calls FolderBrowserDialog and it works. Now my problem is when trying to use that for the place to set a .bmp file I get "The path is not of a legal form" Heres the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;



namespace Paint_AppLication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private bool mouse_down = false;
    static string folderPath = "";
    private Color col = Color.Black;
    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouse_down = true;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouse_down = false;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.X + ", " + e.Y;
        if(mouse_down == true)
        {
            bit = new Bitmap(bit, panel1.Size);
            panel1.BackgroundImage = bit;
            bit.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, col);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        col = colorDialog1.Color;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog directchoosedlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (directchoosedlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            folderPath = directchoosedlg.SelectedPath;
        }

    }
   //My Error Is here
     private Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(folderPath);
}
}
```

Comment: You create a new bitmap every MouseMove event? That is horribly inefficient.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I guess I do,That's so it updates the Panel nearly instantly, But how do I fix the error I'm currently having? And how do I make it more efficient because I do understand it's inefficient in the way that it is, Thank you!

Comment: Umm, just draw on `bit` instead of making a new one every time. basically leave the code in that function the same but get rid of `bit = new Bitmap(bit, panel1.Size);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Done, Now please look at answer 1 and Help me with that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This line:

  ```
  private Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(folderPath);
  ```

  is executed as soon as the instance of `Form1` is created. At this point, `folderPath` isn't initialized to an actual path yet, it's just an empty string. You should initialize the bitmap after you set `folderPath` to an actual path.
- The constructor of the `Bitmap` class takes a path to a file, but you're trying to pass the path to a folder. You should use an `OpenFileDialog` rather than a `FolderBrowserDialog`.

Comment: Understood, How would i do such, while attempting to move the Open file dialog to its own function im getting an error saying  "Cannot Implicitly Change 'System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog' to 'string' " Do i use ToString(); to fix it?

Comment: @Tomas Levesque

Comment: @WilliamAughenbaugh use the FileName property

Comment: @Tomas Levesque Okay, I'm getting no errors in just the code, but once I run the program it says "private Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(folderPath);"

Comment: The path is not of a legal form.

Comment: @WilliamAughenbaugh I already explained why... `folderPath` is not yet initialized at this point. You're trying to create the bitmap too early